# Authentication work only in debug but not release mode

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the sample code realtime database at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database
Everything works find in debug mode. However, if i install the signed apk , download from google play , change the build variant from debug to release in android studio. Signing in will crash.

I have obtained the SHA1 for release and updated the json file accordingly.

I have observed this, do not know if t is relevant. 
If i use debug mode to login successfully, the database will change
In release mode, the change do not appear in the database console

from
a: 
"test@gmail.com"
b: 
"test"

to

email: 
"test@gmail.com"
 username: 
"test"
The error logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: simonhcm.multiplay, PID: 18928
     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
       at com.a.a.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ek.b(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.fb.a(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.fb.c(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.dj.a(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ee.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
       at com.a.a.a.d.a(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.ek.b(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.fb.a(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.fb.c(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.dj.a(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.ee.run(Unknown Source) 
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity simonhcm.multiplay/.MainActivity
W/DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: data_app_crash (1883 > 0 bytes)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6907(456KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 28% free, 41MB/57MB, paused 1.419ms total 107.537ms
E/DropBoxTask: null InputStream
    java.io.IOException: null InputStream
       at wtd.a(:com.google.android.gms:182)
       at wtd.b(:com.google.android.gms:124)
       at wsi.a(:com.google.android.gms:88)
       at com.google.android.gms.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:1176)
       at bdz.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The sign in activity

```
public class SignInActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;
    private Button mSignInButton;
    private Button mSignUpButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Views
        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_email);
        mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_password);
        mSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in);
        mSignUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up);

        // Click listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Check auth on Activity start
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            onAuthSuccess(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn");
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();
        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        hideProgressDialog();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Sign In Failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "signUp");
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();
        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUser:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        hideProgressDialog();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Sign Up Failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
        String username = usernameFromEmail(user.getEmail());

        // Write new user
        writeNewUser(user.getUid(), username, user.getEmail());

        // Go to MainActivity
        startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private String usernameFromEmail(String email) {
        if (email.contains("@")) {
            return email.split("@")[0];
        } else {
            return email;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean result = true;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmailField.getText().toString())) {
            mEmailField.setError("Required");
            result = false;
        } else {
            mEmailField.setError(null);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPasswordField.getText().toString())) {
            mPasswordField.setError("Required");
            result = false;
        } else {
            mPasswordField.setError(null);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // [START basic_write]
    private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
        User user = new User(name, email);

        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
    }
    // [END basic_write]

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_up:
                signUp();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out the problem is at app gradle
minifyEnabled true

Comment: when you enable minify , you also need to specify pro guard rules.

Comment: @SimonHo How did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Atmaram Which specific pro guard rules?